# OpenJDK 1.6 Bug while doing nested type inference?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I have the following sample Java program which compiles fine under a Oracle JDK but not on OpenJDK:

```
public class GenericsBug {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      GenericsBug bug = new GenericsBug();
      // This line causes the error for not finding matching types:
      AResp resp = bug.execute(new AReq());
  }

  public <T extends Request,R extends Response<T>> R execute(T request) {
      return null;
  }
}

class Request { }
class Response<T extends Request> {}

class AReq extends Request {}
class AResp extends Response<AReq> {}
```

Compiling it with

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3635)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)
```

and

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

works fine, but fails with

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

I get the following compile error here:

```
GenericsBug.java:9: type parameters of <R>R cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable R with upper bounds AResp,Response<T>
    AResp resp = bug.execute(new AReq());
                            ^
 1 error
```

So my question is, if this is a bug in OpenJDK or whether I'm doing something wrong here with generics' type inference ?

---

Since in the comments below, there are some question about the usefulness of this code (albeit the question was purely syntax related ;-), here is the given examples with some more meat. It uses a double-dispatch to let the request create the response itself and uses   a parameterized execute to make the usage as typesafe as possible to allow only the same pairs of request and response types. The same scenario could probably done as well with multiple, overloaded `execute()` methods, too. Regardless, whether this code is useful or not, the question about the different syntactic handling between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK 1.6 for this use case remains.

```
 public class Client {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Client client = new Client();

     // AReq and AResp must match, otherwise an compile error will happen
     AResp respA = client.execute(new AReq());
     System.out.println(respA.getAContent());

     // Same for BReq and BResp
     BResp respB = client.execute(new BReq());
     System.out.println(respB.getBContent());
   }

   public <T extends Request,R extends Response<T>> R execute(T request) {
     // Fetch the response somehow, eg. by using a HttpClient:
     String responseBody = "....";
     // Let the request itself create the response
     return request.createResponse(responseBody);
 }

}
// ==================================================================================

// Abstract definition of a requests
abstract class Request {
    abstract <R extends Response<? extends Request>> R createResponse(String content); 
}
class Response<T extends Request> {}

// Two request/response pairs with specific request/response specific members
class AReq extends Request {
    AResp createResponse(String content) {
        return new AResp(content);
    }
}
class AResp extends Response<AReq> {
    private String aContent;

    public AResp(String pContent) {
        aContent = "AResp: " + pContent;
    }

    public String getAContent() {
        return aContent;
    }
} 

class BReq extends Request {
    BResp createResponse(String content) {
        return new BResp(content);
    }
}
class BResp extends Response<BReq> {
    private String bContent;

    public BResp(String pContent) {
        bContent = "BResp: " + pContent;
    }

    public String getBContent() {
        return bContent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

imagine you have also

`class AResp2 extends Response<AReq> {}`

then both senetences are equally (il)legal:

> AResp resp = bug.execute(new AReq());
>
> AResp2 resp = bug.execute(new AReq());

So I believe OpenJDK is correct here.

What can be done to fix the problem:

> public  Response execute(T request) {  }

and then manually cast Response to AResp.

Or tightly connect request to response, so that compiler could unambiguously determine response type by request type:

```
class Request<R extends Response> { }
class Response {}

class AReq extends Request<AResp> {}
class AResp extends Response {}

public <T extends Request<R>, R extends Response> R execute(T request) {  }
```

Comment: "So I believe OpenJDK is correct here." No, OpenJDK did not complain about `GenericsBug.execute` at all. It just complained that it couldn't figure out the type parameter involved on the `resp` line (perhaps it has a less advanced type inference system). But it is possible to infer a correct type (as evidenced by the Oracle JDK), and you can also manually help it out: `AResp resp = bug.<AResp>execute(new AReq()); AResp2 resp = bug.<AResp2>execute(new AReq());` I'm sure this would compile. Yes, what he is doing with `GenericsBug.execute` doesn't make sense, but it is not illegal.

Comment: In fact, declaring the types explicitly as in `bug.<ARequest,AReponse>` works perfectly. Its only about the inference algorithm which fails for the OpenJDK case. Honestly, I even think that this use case makes sense. Consider a general client class, with several Request/Response pairs which are used always together. An example of this patten can be found for the Jolokia [Java-Client](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/clients.html#client-java) and works smoothely (except for this annoying compile error, which needs not happen IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `execute` is *too* generic, as Alexei's answer illustrates.  How could you ever implement a method that can return any desired subclass `R` of `Response< T >` for any `T` (although `return null` should technically work, which is why I think the Oracle JDK is actually correct).

`GenericsBug` the class, and not `GenericsBug.execute` the method, should take `T` and `R` as parameters.

Comment: For my use case, consider `GenericBug` to be a more general `Client` class. Eg. consider it to be an `HttpClient` with pairs of  `PostRequest` / `PostResponse`, `GetRequest` / `GetResponse`, .... each of this classes providing specific access methods. So it would be nice (and indeed works for the Oracle JDK case) to call 'GetRequest getReq = ....; GetResponse resp = client.execute(getRequest)` in a type safe manner. See also the [Jolokia Java-Client](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/clients.html#client-java) for a real world example of this pattern.

Comment: I didn't spend too long looking at your link, but what I gather is that they have a finite set of overloads to achieve what you want to solve in a single generic method.  The problem for me is that once you have enough information to provide such a method, you won't need to call it.

Comment: You are right, one could probably do it with overloaded methods (and different return types) as well, but using generics here has some technical advantages (and reduces duplicated code). BTW, I just found out that with OpenJDK and Oracle JDK 7 the code snippet above compiles smoothely, too. So I really assume that it is a bug (or deficite in the inference algorithm) of OpenJDK 6. And yes, its only about compilation. During runtime everything works perfectly as expected.

Comment: My point is that it appears you are attempting to fit a square peg (ad-hoc polymorphism) into a round hole (parametric polymorphism).  `return null` is parametric, so I agree that the compiler should be satisfied with that.  But when it comes time to provide a real implementation, you are either going to be doing non-parametric things (like if-ladders on `instanceof`) or trivial parametric things (using collaborators to do the actual work).  Some more code would help clarify.

Comment: The example was confessedly stripped down to much in order to illustrate the different compiler handling in Oracle JDK and OpenJDK. I just added my use case to the error description to make it a bit more clear, how I use this construct. But its probably easier to add explicite add 6 overloaded `execute()` methods doing this dispatch explicitly instead of wrapping my head around generics (again and again ;-(